# cant load 2 NSMutable arrays in my UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, nsmutablearray, subview

my app has one scroll view and one tableview added as subview. on scroll view i have two buttons. i want to load two separate arrays in my tableview on pressing these buttons.but for some reason it just doesnt happen. can anyone please help me what i am doing wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
worldArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];
IndiaArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"abc",@"pqr",@"xyz", nil];
 [self PutButtoninScrollView:2];
}

-(void)PutButtoninScrollView:(int)numberOfbuttons
{
    myButton1=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    myButton1= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    myButton1.frame=CGRectMake(5, 5, 70, 30);
    [myButton1 setTitle:@"World" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton1 setTag:1];
    myButton1.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [myButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(ListViewAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.myScrollView addSubview:myButton1];

    myButton2=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    myButton2= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton2.frame=CGRectMake(80, 5, 70, 30);
    [myButton2 setTitle:@"India" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(ListViewAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.myScrollView addSubview:myButton2];

 [self.myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(160, 35)];
    _myScrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.myScrollView];
}

-(void)ListViewAction:(id)sender
{

    if ([[sender currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"World"])
    {
        NSLog(@"successful ");            
        [tempArray addObject: worldArray];
    }
    else if ([[sender currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"India"])
    {
         NSLog(@"successful again");
        [tempArray addObject: IndiaArray];
    }
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tempArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier]autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detailViewCont=[[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:detailViewCont animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: reload your table in ListViewAction method [yourTableview reloaddata];

Comment: @SumitMundra did it. still nothing

Comment: use [tempArray addObjectsFromArray: worldArray]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below code

in .h

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray;
NSMutableArray *worldArray;
NSMutableArray *IndiaArray;
```

in .m

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   tempArray = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   worldArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];
   IndiaArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"abc",@"pqr",@"xyz", nil];
   [self PutButtoninScrollView:2];
  }



-(void)ListViewAction:(id)sender
 {

     if ([[sender currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"World"])
      {
        [tempArray removeAllObjects];
        [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:worldArray];

      }
    else if ([[sender currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"India"])
     {
        [tempArray removeAllObjects];
        [tempArray addObjectsFromArray: IndiaArray];
     }

  [yourTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: did it. nothing happens mytableview appears blank

Comment: check if your tempArray is nil when it returns count in "numberOfRowsInSection"  if yes checkif you have initialized tempArray or not.

Comment: see my updated answer and check the initial object initialization.

Comment: i have added nslog statemnts just to check my sender is returning to listview action, it works fine. so i am getting message "successful" and "successful again" when i press 1st and second button respectively

Comment: initialized tempArray in viewDidLoad but still it is returning nil in numberOfRowsInSection.

Comment: please nslog your tempArray like 
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"tempArray count %d",[tempArray count]);
    return [tempArray count];
}

to make sure that your array has value. if it returns 0 your temparray is not initialized.

Comment: and try using my answer method instead of yours, your code has few bugs in it.

Comment: now you have got the problem your tempArray is not taking values from your array just replace your --(void)ListViewAction:(id)sender whole method from mine above given method and then try.

Comment: finally did it just initialised the worldArray, IndiaArray and tempArray in ListviewAction instead of viewDidLoad

Comment: that will rise to memory leakage boy ...like this you will be initializing your global objects again and again with every tap of your button.

Comment: should make those objects local then? and release them in listviewAction itself or viewDidLoad?

Comment: then you won't be able to return arrayCount in tableview delegates

Comment: just did product clean and rebuild and guess what It works the way told. all initializations in viewDidLoad. nothing in LIStViewAction.Thanx for your kind help